# Ionic + Firebase unable return a promise with fetched data from DB

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and Ionic and currently trying to get some data from the server as a certain view is loaded. Right now I am able to get the data inside the service, but I'm unable to return the fetched `data` as a promise to a controller. This is the code that calls the service:

```
 $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;       
    fireBaseService.getDataFromDB(user.uid).then(function(res){
      console.log(res); 
    });
```

And here is the service that calls the Firebase API:

```
this.getDataFromDB = function(uid){
    return firebase.database().ref('table/' + uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val(); //data is available here
        return data;
    });
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: fireBaseService.getExpensesFromDB(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but I think usually responses from the `firebaseService` return `Observables`, but you are trying to access it as a `Promise` via `then`. You might want to `.subscribe()` instead?

Comment: I get the data inside the service, just unable to return it to the controller the call was made from. Can you elaborate about the subscribe method?

Comment: Where exactly is `getExpensesFromDB(...)` defined in your code? Is it the method where you log to the console? If this is the case, you are missing a return statement.

Comment: The `getDataFromDB` method lives inside a service called `fireBaseService` and is injected into the controller. The logging to console part is inside the controller after calling the service. I get the data inside the service and I return the firebase ref and the response itself (two return statements)

Comment: Yes, but in your error message it says `fireBaseService.getExpensesFromDB(...).then is not a function`, but I can't see this method anywhere in your code. Maybe you are calling a function that is not defined.

Comment: It is there, `fireBaseService.getDataFromDB(user.uid).then(function(res)..`

Comment: Try `fireBaseService.getDataFromDB(user.uid).subscribe(function(res)..` instead

Comment: Thanks, will update later

Answer (score 0):

```
call from controller
fireBaseService.getDataFromDB(user.uid, function(res) {
  console.log(res);
}

service call
getDataFromDB = function(uid, callback){
    return firebase.database().ref('table/' + uid).on('value', function(snapshot) {
        var data = snapshot.val(); //data is available here
        callback(data);
    });
}
```